# How can I install CentOS 7.0 from shell after booting from Live CD?

Tags: centos

I downloaded the Gnome version of CentOS 7.0 and booted it in a VM using VirtualBox. The mouse didn't work right so when I tried to launch the "Install to Hard Disk" task, nothing happened.

I rebooted the VM and appended 3 to the kernel boot options to boot into the console instead of the GUI desktop. So now I'm at a root shell prompt, but what program can I launch to run the text installer so that I can install the OS on disk?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/365118/how-can-i-install-centos-6-without-the-gui

check out above link may help you.

Comment: Thanks. I read that link and followed the instructions to "...go to the end of the command line containing vmlinuz, at the end add the word text." But it still took me into the GUI desktop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [the DVD or Everything images](http://www.centos.org/download/) or the netinstall image to install, instead of the Live CD that you are trying to use. You then have access to the regular installer. The Live CD does not include anaconda, the installation program, but only a custom installer that installs only that particular system image.

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally RHEL/CentOS installation media has offered possibility to type in to GRUB boot prompt `linux text` and let the installer start in ncurses-based text mode.

I have not checked if this has changed in CentOS 7.0, though.

Comment: I think the "linux text" command was from the install prompt (which I got in prior releases like 5.10). The issue I have is that all I can do is modify the kernel boot options (the one where you specify vmlinuz).

Comment: Maybe I just need to download a different version of the install media.